# Sending a SMS with the iPhone via ssh

Tags: iphone, ssh, sms

I have a server and i want it to send an sms to me progammatically using my second and never used jailbroken iphone. 
It has a sim card and everything else, so I'm just going to hock it up o the server for energy and will use it as a kind of sms alert system.

I am going to program a Batch file or a C# Application so i guess ssh would be the best choice.

I have tried the **SendSMS** app from **Cydia** but it keeps freezing at "Sending SMS...".

After that I have been searching the Internet for over 3 hours and have found nothing helpful.

stackoverflow is my last hope!

my iPhone: iPhone4 , 5.0.1(9A405), BB 04.11.08

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the latest Bitesms supports sending SMS via commandline, but on older version, it can.

```
/Applications/biteSMS.app/biteSMS -send -carrier recipient’s_phone_number “Your message here”
```

Quick [Google search returns this](http://www.iphone-my.com/iphone/how-to-remotely-send-text-messages-from-command-line/), so you might want to have a look

Comment: Thanks alot, finally managed to do it with BiteSMS..

But the code is :
/Applications/biteSMS.app/biteSMS -send recipient’s_phone_number “Your message here”

you dont have to enter the carrier..

Answer (score 0):

In general, you won't be able to do this from an un-jailbroken iPhone. Apps can't send texts without user intervention.

Interestingly, AT&T has a non-iphone-specific SMS API that you might be able to use. I know nothing about it (except that it exists).

If you are on a jailbroken phone, presumably all you need is an app that listens on a network port, e.g., an HTTP listener, and forwards messages as you've formatted them via some jailbroken mechanism.

Comment: Yes my iPhone is jailbroken.. the thing is i don't really want to learn ObjectiveC as well = ) 

The idea with the HTTP listener is quite good and a could set something like that up on my other machine. Just the sending an SMS would preferably happen over my WiFi --> using ssh --> to iPhone.

Now I'm not that familiar with my possibilities regarding apps that could actually do that with a easy to use interface.

About the AT&T part: I live in Switzerland so that won't be an option.